# Issues while loading HBASE from Pyspark : Failed to load converter: org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am getting the below error message while loading HBASE from PySpark.

"Failed to load converter: org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"

I am using spark 2.0 and Hbase 1.1.2.2.5.0.0-1245

Using the below steps to load Hbase

```
datamap=temp_rdd.map( lambda (x,y): (str(x),[str(x),"cf1","a",y]))

host='xyz'
table='test'
conf = {"hbase.zookeeper.quorum": host,
 "hbase.mapred.outputtable": table,
 "mapreduce.outputformat.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableOutputFormat",
 "mapreduce.job.output.key.class": "org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable",
 "mapreduce.job.output.value.class": "org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable"}
keyConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringToImmutableBytesWritableConverter"
valueConv = "org.apache.spark.examples.pythonconverters.StringListToPutConverter"

 datamap.saveAsNewAPIHadoopDataset(conf=conf,keyConverter=keyConv,valueConverter=valueConv)
```

Can anyone please help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class only exist in the example jar of spark.
To use it you need to add the spark-examples.jar to your spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath.

Comment: Thanks RanP..The issue got resolved after executing the script with the jar file